# Azure Mobile Services : can't login with Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

In an Android app running on a real phone with a 4.4.2 (not emulator), Xamarin.Auth runs successfully to retrieve Access Token from Twitter. The problem is when using these credentials against Azure Mobile Services. The method LoginAsync never comes back.. If I put this code in form of a task and I wait after the task, the task is going long running with no end.

Without authentication, the application was working fine and I could push data to the service.

```
Client = new MobileServiceClient(applicationURL, applicationKey);
JObject token = new JObject();
token.Add("access_token", "here is the token of the user");
Client.CurrentUser = await Client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Twitter, token);
```

Basically, I tried to follow the guideline of this article but it's not working for me : http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-xamarin-mobile-services-how-to-use-client-library/

I use the stable version 1.3.1 of WindowsAzure.MobileServices. I can't install the pre-release version because I also need the package Azure Mobile Services SQliteStore and this package is not available in pre-release.

any ideas how to turn around that problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Mobile Services does not presently support the POST of Twitter tokens (which is what this method does). This is sometimes referred to as the "client-directed flow" since the token is obtained on the client and provided to the server.

The [REST API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj710106.aspx) appears to be a little bit dated, but the additions of to Facebook, Google, and Microsoft Account to the .NET backend is captured in [this announcement](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/27/logging-in-with-google-microsoft-and-facebook-sdks-to-azure-mobile-services/).

If you wish to log in with Twitter using Mobile Services, you will need to use the server-directed flow. This is done by omitting the `token` parameter to  `LoginAsync()`.

```
await Client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Twitter);
```

The server flow tutorial can be found [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-xamarin-android-get-started-users/).